# JavaFx: I need something similar to this but for a TableView instead of a ListView

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

I took a stab at this yesterday but the TableView documentation has me a bit confused. After working on it for a couple of hours I gave up.  Just wondering if any javafx experts out there can help me with this. I want to update a TableView in a background thread periodically when items in my database change.
Rather than post my entire application I have tried to break it down to a simple example.  Replace all occurrences of ListView with TableView and ....

Then what?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 * An example of triggering a JavaFX ListView when an item is modified.
 * 
 * Displays a list of strings.  It iterates through the strings adding
 * exclamation marks with 2 second pauses in between.  Each modification is
 * accompanied by firing an event to indicate to the ListView that the value
 * has been modified.
 * 
 * @author Mark Fashing
 */
public class ListViewTest extends Application {

    /**
     * Informs the ListView that one of its items has been modified.
     *
     * @param listView The ListView to trigger.
     * @param newValue The new value of the list item that changed.
     * @param i The index of the list item that changed.
     */    
    public static <T> void triggerUpdate(ListView<T> listView, T newValue, int i) {
        EventType<? extends ListView.EditEvent<T>> type = ListView.editCommitEvent();
        Event event = new ListView.EditEvent<>(listView, type, newValue, i);
        listView.fireEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create a list of mutable data.  StringBuffer works nicely.
        final List<StringBuffer> listData = Stream.of("Fee", "Fi", "Fo", "Fum")
                .map(StringBuffer::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        final ListView<StringBuffer> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll(listData);
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(listView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        // Modify an item in the list every 2 seconds.
        new Thread(() -> {
            IntStream.range(0, listData.size()).forEach(i -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(listData.get(i));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    // Where the magic happens.
                    listData.get(i).append("!");
                    triggerUpdate(listView, listData.get(i), i);
                });            
            });
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here is my first attempt:

Create a person class....

```
package org.pauquette.example;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {
       private final SimpleStringProperty email;
       private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
       private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

       Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
           this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
           this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
           this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email.get();
       }

       public String getFirstName() {
           return firstName.get();
       }

       public String getLastName() {
           return lastName.get();
       }

       public void setEmail(String fName) {
           email.set(fName);
       }

       public void setFirstName(String fName) {
           firstName.set(fName);
       }

       public void setLastName(String fName) {
           lastName.set(fName);
       }
}
```

Create an extremely simple model class...

```
package org.pauquette.example;

import javafx.collections.*;

public class PeopleModel {

    private ObservableList<Person> people=FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
            );

    public ObservableList<Person> getPeople() {
          return people;
    }

}
```

Now create a TableView of just firstName and build the columns then update the firstName every 2 seconds.......

```
package org.pauquette.example;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 * An example of triggering a JavaFX TableView when an item is modified.
 * 
 * Displays a list of strings.  It iterates through the strings adding
 * exclamation marks with 2 second pauses in between.  Each modification is
 * accompanied by firing an event to indicate to the TableView that the value
 * has been modified.
 * 
 * @author Mark Fashing-Modified for TableView by Bryan Pauquette
 */
public class TableViewTest extends Application {

    /*
    public static <T> void triggerUpdate(TableView<T> listView, T newValue, int i) {
        EventType<? extends TableView.EditEvent<T>> type = TableView.editCommitEvent();
        Event event = new TableView.EditEvent<>(listView, type, newValue, i);
        listView.fireEvent(event);
    }*/

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final TableView<Person> listView = new TableView<Person>();
        final PeopleModel model=new PeopleModel();
        final ObservableList<Person> listData=model.getPeople();
        listView.getItems().addAll(listData);
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        buildColumns(listView,listData);
        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        // Modify an item in the list every 2 seconds.
        new Thread(() -> {
            IntStream.range(0, listData.size()).forEach(i -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(listData.get(i));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    // Where the magic happens.
                    Person p=listData.get(i);
                    p.setFirstName(new StringBuilder(p.getFirstName()).append("!").toString());
                    //triggerUpdate(listView, listData.get(i), i);
                });            
            });
        }).start();
    }


    private void buildColumns(TableView<Person> listView,ObservableList<Person> listData) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> dataCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
        dataCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));     
        listView.getColumns().add(dataCol);
        listView.setItems(listData);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The method I am struggling with is triggerUpdate.....

I want the firstName column to get updated in the view with an appended exclamation point every 2 seconds just like in the original simple list view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code.....

```
package org.pauquette.example;

import java.util.Observable;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class Person extends Observable {
       private final SimpleStringProperty email;
       private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
       private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

       Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
           this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
           this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
           this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email.get();
       }

       public String getFirstName() {
           return firstName.get();
       }

       public String getLastName() {
           return lastName.get();
       }

       public void setEmail(String emailIn) {
           email.setValue(emailIn);
           setChanged();
           notifyObservers(email);
       }

       public void setFirstName(String fNameIn) {
           firstName.setValue(fNameIn);
           setChanged();
           notifyObservers(firstName);

       }

       public void setLastName(String lNameIn) {
           lastName.setValue(lNameIn);
           setChanged();
           notifyObservers();
       }

    public ObservableValue<String> firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

And......

```
    package org.pauquette.example;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
/**
 * An example of triggering a JavaFX TableView when an item is modified.
 * 
 * Displays a list of strings.  It iterates through the strings adding
 * exclamation marks with 2 second pauses in between.  Each modification is
 * accompanied by firing an event to indicate to the TableView that the value
 * has been modified.
 * 
 * @author Mark Fashing-Modified for TableView by Bryan Pauquette
 */
public class TableViewTest extends Application {

    /*
    public static <T> void triggerUpdate(TableView<T> listView, T newValue, int i) {
        EventType<? extends TableView.EditEvent<T>> type = TableView.editCommitEvent();
        Event event = new TableView.EditEvent<>(listView, type, newValue, i);
        listView.fireEvent(event);
    }*/

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final TableView<Person> listView = new TableView<Person>();
        final PeopleModel model=new PeopleModel();
        final ObservableList<Person> listData=model.getPeople();

       /* int row=0;
        for (Person p : listData) {
            p.addObserver(new PersonObserver(listView,row));
            row++;
        }*/
        listView.getItems().addAll(listData);


        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        buildColumns(listView,listData);
        root.getChildren().add(listView);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        // Modify an item in the list every 2 seconds.
        new Thread(() -> {
            IntStream.range(0, listData.size()).forEach(i -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(listData.get(i));
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    // Where the magic happens.
                    Person p=listData.get(i);
                    p.setFirstName(new StringBuilder(p.getFirstName()).append("!").toString());
                    //triggerUpdate(listView, listData.get(i), i);
                });            
            });
        }).start();
    }




    private void buildColumns(TableView<Person> listView,ObservableList<Person> listData) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> dataCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
        //dataCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        dataCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> p) {
                // p.getValue() returns the Person instance for a particular TableView row
                return p.getValue().firstNameProperty();
            }
         });


        listView.getColumns().add(dataCol);
        listView.setItems(listData);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need to extend Observable in your pojo class. Still works. when I removed that.